# Trouble interacting with RDS file in python

Tags: python, r

I want to open a RDS file on fish lengths in python and convert it to sorted lists of tuples based on size and location classes, perform basic statistics, generate a graph, and save the results in a .CSV. I am using [pyreadr](https://github.com/ofajardo/pyreadr) I have been able to read the file as an OrderedDict,(verified using `type(result) <class 'collection.OrderedDict'>`) but haven't been able to print single rows or columns. I can print the whole dataset but I have no control.

```
import pyreadr
myfile ='C:\\Users\\Tim\\Downloads\\fishData.RDS'
result = pyreadr.read_r(myfile)
print(result.keys())
df1=result[None]
print(df1)
```

My Output...

```
odict_keys([None])
OrderedDict([(None,       size  fishLength     location
0      fry   10.420310  mainChannel
1      fry    9.165523  mainChannel
2      fry    7.005817  mainChannel
3      fry    7.199168   floodPlain
4      fry    3.392063  mainChannel
..     ...         ...          ...
173  smolt   31.765081   floodPlain
174  smolt   32.573470   floodPlain
175  smolt   31.204408  mainChannel
176  smolt   30.948726   floodPlain
177  smolt   28.414746  mainChannel

[178 rows x 3 columns])])
```

I get my data, however when I use

```
len(results) 
1
```

It is all in one giant item that I can't find out how to get the actual length data out to process it. Needing help accessing the individual rows to extract them for the `.CSV`.

Comment: Why does this question have an R tag?

Comment: @G5W They're trying to open an [RDS file](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.3.2/topics/readRDS) which is a serialised R object.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `len(df1)` to get the number of rows of your data frame? From your above code `result` is still just the ordered dictionary?

Answer (score 3):

When you use the `read_r` function it will return a dictionary where  the keys are the names of the objects. RDS files are a single serialised R object (as opposed to RData files which can store multiple R objects) and consequently there is only one object in the dictionary with the key being `None`. Here's a quick example.

**R Code**

```r
df <- data.frame(x=11:20,
                 y=sin(1:10),
                 z=rep(c('foo', 'bar'), each=5)
)

saveRDS(df, 'file.rds')
```

**Python Code**

```py
import pyreadr

result = pyreadr.read_r('file.rds')
result[None]

    x         y    z
0  11  0.841471  foo
1  12  0.909297  foo
2  13  0.141120  foo
3  14 -0.756802  foo
4  15 -0.958924  foo
5  16 -0.279415  bar
6  17  0.656987  bar
7  18  0.989358  bar
8  19  0.412118  bar
9  20 -0.544021  bar
```

You're still trying too apply the `len` function to the dictionary. You should save the actual data frame to a new object and manipulate that instead. E.g.

```py
In [2]: df = pyreadr.read_r("file.rds")[None]

In [3]: len(df)
Out[3]: 10

In [4]: df['x']*42
Out[4]: 
0    462
1    504
2    546
3    588
4    630
5    672
6    714
7    756
8    798
9    840
Name: x, dtype: int32
```